# シェルスクリプトのJSON要素で連番を指定したい

Tags: json, shellscript, jq

#### 現状

現在、JSONの訂正作業を行っており、既存のJSONから新しいVal要素(Key:Value)を追加する作業を行っています。

**現在のコード**

```
{
  "total": [
      {
        "name": "sasuke",
        "category": "animal",
        "URL": "https://0000/0000/0000"
      },
       {
        "name": "siro",
        "category": "animal",
        "URL": "https://1111/1111/1111"
      },
       {
        "name": "kuro",
        "category": "animal",
        "URL": "https://2222/2222/2222"
      }
   ]
}
```

#### 問題点

JSONへ新しいVal要素(Key:Value)を追加する際、Valueに追加を記入したいです。
要素を追加するには

```
| jq ' .liveInfo[0] |= .+ {"number": 連番}'
```

で実現できることがわかりましたが、連番部分がどの様にコードを書けば良いかがわかりません。
どなたかご教示をよろしくお願いいたします。

以下実現したいコードになります。

**追加要素**

```
"namber": "連番"
```

**完成コード**

```
{
  "total": [
      {
　　　　"namber": "1"
        "name"："sasuke",
        "category"："animal",
        "URL"："https://0000/0000/0000",
      },
       {
　　　　"namber": "2"
        "name"："siro",
        "category"："animal",
        "URL"："https://1111/1111/1111",
      },
       {
　　　　"namber": "3"
        "name"："kuro",
        "category"："animal",
        "URL"："https://2222/2222/2222",
      }
   ]
```

Answer (score 2):

以下は `reduce` を使う方法です。

```sh
$ jq -r '
    reduce range(.total|length) as $i(.;.total[$i].number="\($i+1)")
  ' data.json
{
  "total": [
    {
      "name": "sasuke",
      "category": "animal",
      "URL": "https://0000/0000/0000",
      "number": "1"
    },
    {
      "name": "siro",
      "category": "animal",
      "URL": "https://1111/1111/1111",
      "number": "2"
    },
    {
      "name": "kuro",
      "category": "animal",
      "URL": "https://2222/2222/2222",
      "number": "3"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: metropolisさん　連絡ありがとうございます。頂きました内容通りコーディングした結果、上手く動作いたしました。大変ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

テキスト処理と割り切るならawkで加工するのが簡単です。
`"name":`を含む行を見つけたら、printfで名前がnumberの値として連番を出力します。

```
awk '
BEGIN{
    no= 1
}
/\"name\":/{
    printf("        \"number\": \"%d\",\n", no++)
}
{
    print $0
}
' jsonファイル
```

【出力結果】

```
{
  "total": [
      {
        "number": "1",
        "name": "sasuke",
        "category": "animal",
        "URL": "https://0000/0000/0000"
      },
       {
        "number": "2",
        "name": "siro",
        "category": "animal",
        "URL": "https://1111/1111/1111"
      },
       {
        "number": "3",
        "name": "kuro",
        "category": "animal",
        "URL": "https://2222/2222/2222"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: akira ejiriさん　連絡ありがとうございます。大変助かりました。今後ともよろしくお願いいたします。